# ElasticSearch update property value using script

Tags: elasticsearch

I've the following documents of type 'tags'. Now i want to update the documents i.e. i want remove the tag "hello".

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "tags": [ "hello", "stackoverflow, "promising" ]
}

{
    "id": 2,
    "tags": [ "stackoverflow, "promising" ]
}

{
    "id": 3,
    "tags": [ "hello" ]
}
```

So is it possible in ElasticSearch to do it using one query to get the following result

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "tags": [ "stackoverflow, "promising" ]
}

{
    "id": 2,
    "tags": [ "stackoverflow, "promising" ]
}

{
    "id": 3,
    "tags": [ ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [update query plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery) for this. Install this plugin and then run following query.

```
{
"query": {
"match_all": {}
 },
 "script" : "ctx._source.tags.remove('hello')"
}
```

Hope this helps.